# Zonal statistics for multiple rasters for each polygon within a shapefile

Tags: r, loops, statistics, raster

I need to calculate zonal statistics (both mean and standard deviation) for each polygon within a shapefile. This I need to calculate from around one hundred rasters, stored in .tiff format. Each raster includes an index per specific date.

The zonal statistics I need to collect in the table, which structure must be as follows:

| Polygon ID | Suffix | date | mean | stdev | date | mean | stdev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 418111111 | NDVI | 03/01/2019 | 0.36555 | 15.26314 | 06/01/2019 | 0.26555 | 25.33333 |
| 523333333 | NDVI | 03/01/2019 | 0.52325 | 16.36514 | 06/01/2019 | 0.76255 | 26.33333 |

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem? If you can show us a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of what you've tried and where you've come into a problem, you'll be much more likely to get an answer.

Comment: I would suggest to 1/ match and crop/mask rasters with corresponding polygons (`terra` package), 2/ calculate the desired values: mean, stdev and 3/ collect in data frame (table).

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but if you're working in python, you may find [xagg](https://github.com/ks905383/xagg) useful; it allows you to aggregate raster data onto polygons. It currently only supports mean calculations, however.